# Golang сборка приложения для разных ОС

Tags: golang

Планируется перевести довольно крупный проект на Go, поэтому хочется узнать о подводных камнях заранее.

Интересующие вопросы

1. Собираем приложение на системе windows 10. Будет ли наше приложение стабильно(более менее стабильно) работать разных системах от win7 до win10?
   Или же лучше проводить сборку с статической линковкой на наиболее старой версии, в надежде что в новых все необходимые бибилиотеки уже установленны.
   Или же лучше на самой новой ОС, где самые новые библиотеки?
   Или же не имеет разницы?
2. На своей рабочей станции (ОС debian) выполнил

   go tool dist list

Увидел строку windows/amd64. Как я понимаю я могу произвести сборку (используя определенные флаги) для windows из под своей linux системы.
Вопрос тот же: Стабильно ли это будет работать?
Понимаю что системы разные, разные подходы, нюансы. Условимся что приложение не имеет специфичных для данной ОС участков кода (не важно linux или windows).

Разумеется будем проводить тестирование перед релизом. Но все это время и деньги. Возможно у кого-то был подобный опыт и кто-либо скажет мне: "Все будет хорошо работать на любой системе" или "Нет, не делай так, лучше собирай приложение под конкретную ОС"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практического опыта разработки конкретно для *Windows*
у меня, увы, не так много, но кое-какой информацией
поделиться постараюсь.

1. Судя по официальной [*Wiki*](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Windows),
   *Windows 7* ещё поддерживается, а вот *XP*
   и *Vista* — уже нет. Насколько я понимаю,
   это значит, что программа должна работать плюс-минус одинаково
   на системах от «Семёрки» и выше.
2. Я компилировал *CLI*-приложения для *Windows*
   (и *Mac OS X*, но тут это не так важно)
   с *Linux*-машины (*Ubuntu 16.04*), и они работали
   без особых проблем. Главную проблему могут представлять внешние
   *C*-зависимости, так как для их корректной компиляции потребуется
   кросс-компилятор *C*. Если ваше приложение *C*
   не использует, то проблем должно быть значительно меньше.

См. также: [*WindowsCrossCompiling*](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling).